# MySQL: difference between two timestamps in seconds?

Tags: sql, mysql, timestamp

Is it possible to calculate difference between two timestamps in MySQL and get output result in seconds?

Like `2010-11-29 13:16:55 - 2010-11-29 13:13:55` should give 180 seconds.

Thank you.

Comment: A very similar question was asked a day ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289828/calculates-difference-between-two-dates-in-php/

Comment: @Orbling: No, the result is very different because the output is in hh:mm:ss

Comment: @OMG My answer to that question, the accepted one, is in hh:mm:ss - the other answers are not, hence it includes his answer.  Which you have restated below.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to convert the DATETIME into the value in seconds, starting from Jan 1st, 1970:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-11-29 13:16:55') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-11-29 13:13:55') as output
```

Result:

```
output
-------
180
```

An easy way to deal with if you're not sure which value is bigger than the other -- use the [ABS function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs):

```
SELECT ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.datetime_col1) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.datetime_col2)) as output
```

Comment: fails for DATEs before 1970-01-01

Comment: thanks, James. I'll put that to my others. I'm old so for me getting my birthday in seconds matters. :oP

Answer (score 166):

I do not think the accepted answer is a good universal solution!

This is because the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function fails for DATEs before 1970-01-01 (and for dates in the far future using 32 bit integers). This may happen easily for the day of birth of many living people.

A better solution is:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2010-11-29 13:13:55', '2010-11-29 13:16:55')
```

Which can be modified to return DAY YEAR MONTH HOUR and MINUTE too!

Comment: is their any way to convert the result into hr:min:sec format ?

Comment: This works perfectly. However, the answer is reversed (second date - first date) is the answer. TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:00:00') returns -1 not 1. Thanks

Comment: @Kareem : The OP wanted 180 as result. That is what my example code gives.

Comment: @coolDude: SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,  '2010-11-29 13:13:55', '2010-11-29 13:16:55')) would do the trick.

Comment: @OderWat thanks for the reply .. i solved the problem long time back 

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, EndTime)) as executionTime from abc

Comment: @OderWat your example is perfect, I just wanted to make it clear to others that it is the other way around because it took me a few attempts till I worked it out. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

TIMESTAMPDIFF  method only works with datetime format.  If you want the difference between just two times  like '11:10:00' minus '10:20:00'  then use

```
select TIME_TO_SEC('11:10:00')-TIME_TO_SEC('10:20:00')
```

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF will work for 'time' data types.
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , cast('08:22:03' as time), cast('09:59:03' as time))